# Why FOR /F loop in batch file skips first empty token before the delimiter?

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

I'm struggling to understand the following behavior of the batch file.

This loop:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=$" %%A in ('echo 123$456') DO (
        
        echo A-%%A B-%%B
        
)
```

Returns result: `A-123 B-456`

But this loop:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=$" %%A in ('echo $456') DO (
        
        echo A-%%A B-%%B
        
)
```

Returns: `A-456 B-`

Why is `456` considered an `%%A` in the second example, even though it's placed after the delimiter?

Is it possible to make this loop return `A- B-456`, when the first token is empty?

Comment: do not know if this solve your problem, but try to use `("123$456")` instead of `('echo 123$456')`

Comment: Because leading delimiter strings are skipped by `delims=`. Assuming you have a string that could start with `$` in a variable `var`, try `for /f "tokens=2,3 delims=$" %%A in (`echo X$%var%') do echo A-%%A B-%%B`